# IIS: How to override some php.ini settings with a custom .ini file?

Tags: php, iis, ini

Is it possible to load a custom .ini file that overrides the fat messy php.ini from the distribution package?

On unix systems I believe this can be achieved by putting additional ini files inside `/etc/php.d` but I'm not sure about IIS.

The question is pretty straightforward: Can I define an additional `.ini` file that adds or overloads the standard `php.ini` settings, for example:

`php.ini` is located in `c:\windows` and is the loaded configuration file.
`myphp.ini` is my custom configuration

Where to put `myphp.in`i so that both `php.ini` and `myphp.ini` are loaded and `myphp.ini` is loaded after `php.ini`?

Is there a 'Scan this dir for additional .ini files ' under Windows?

Comment: http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/where_php_ini_is_loaded_from

Comment: I'm not sure that solves his problem, seems to me he want's to load php.ini and then load another .ini file that overwrites that.

Comment: @Toby Allen this is correct

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this might give you an idea on how to have a custom php.ini: [Enable Per-Site PHP Configuration on IIS 7 and IIS 6.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/enable-per-site-php-configuration-on-iis-60-and-iis-7-and-above)

Hope it helps.